# Permanently altering sys.path ... good idea or no?

Tags: python

I have to append sys.path in order for one of my scripts to work.  As I will be doing this often, I was considering permanently adding the path.

Is this generally considered safe?

Also, if my main script appends sys.path, do I need to do so for every module used in that script, or are the changes global?

Thanks!

Comment: "permanently adding the path"?  Do you mean "installing the module required to make the script work"?  What do you mean by "permanently adding"?

Comment: @S.Lott -  I was just typing that same question lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you find yourself commonly adding elements to `sys.path`, adding them permanently can be a good idea.  However you should not do this by editing `sys.path` directly, it is best accomplished by setting the [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable.

There is some documentation on [how to set PYTHONPATH on Windows](http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables), and [this article](http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles/030.html) has some good information for setting environment variables on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually best to do it at the start of a script.  The main reason is portability.  If you move the script from one folder to another, or even worse, a different computer... it's not going to work.

The changes are almost always global.  The exception is when you import path from sys, instead of importing sys.

```
# pathprinter.py
import sys
print sys.path

# tester.py
from sys import path
path = ['a', 'completely', 'new', 'value']
import pathprinter
   # Original path printed
```

Comment: `from sys import path; path = (anything)` just overwrites the local variable named `path` -- it doesn't do anything relating to sys.path, module importing or anything. It just reassigns a local variable.